# BasicAuth and setting a User model which reference e-mail address

Tags: php, atk4

I'm just getting to grips with the shiny new ATK 4.2 which looks very nice. However, I'm having trouble with the BasicAuth class. I want to extend the BasicAuth using the User model. However, my User model does not contain an 'email' field, rather it references a Person model which does contain the e-mail address.

The DB table structure is as follows:

Person Table

- id: primary key
- name: char
- room_number: int
- email: char

User Table

- id: primary key
- person_id: foreign key to Person Table (id)
- password: char

The ATK4.2 classes are below:

### Person Model

```
class Model_Person extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='person';

function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->addField('name');
    $this->addField('roomnumber');
    $this->addField('email');
}
}
```

### User Model

## The 'user' table contains the password field.

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='user';

function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->hasOne('Person');
}
}
```

### User Auth class

```
class UserAuth extends BasicAuth {

function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this->setModel('Model_User', 'email', 'password');
    $this->getModel()->addField('password')->system(true);
    $this->usePasswordEncryption('sha256/salt');
}
}
```

### Manager page.

// Administrator manages the tables in the mySQL database.

```
class page_mgr extends Page {

function init() {
    parent::init();

    $tabs=$this->add('Tabs');

    $crud=$tabs->addTab('Users')->add('CRUD');
    $crud->setModel('User');

    if($crud->grid){

        // Add prompt using user model id field.
        $crud->grid->addColumn('prompt','set_password_prompt');

        if($_GET['set_password_prompt']){
            $auth = $this->add('UserAuth');
            // load User from DB using row ID.
            $model = $auth->getModel()->loadData($_GET['set_password_prompt']);

            $model->set('password', $_GET['value'])->debug()->update();
            $this->js()->univ()->successMessage('Changed password for '.$model->ref('person_id')->get('email'))
              ->execute();
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I try to set the user password in the CRUD, I get the following error after pressing 'ok'.

#

```
Error in AJAXec response: SyntaxError: invalid XML attribute value
```

BaseException

Model field was not loaded

Additional information:

```
Raised by object: Object Model_User(testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user)
id: 1
field: email
```

Possible Actions:

```
Debug this Model
```

/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/BaseException.php:38

```
Stack trace:
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/BaseException.php    :38     BaseException BaseException->collectBasicData(Null, 1, 0)
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :292    BaseException   BaseException->__construct("Model field was not loaded") / : (testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user Model_User->exception("Model field was not loaded")
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/Model/Table.php  :87     Loggercall_user_func_array(Array(2), Array(1))
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/Model.php    :115    testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user   Model_User->exception("Model field was not loaded")
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/Model.php    :184    testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user   Model_User->get("email")
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/Auth/Basic.php   :123    testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user   Model_User->offsetGet("email") /: Logger{closure}(Object(Model_User))
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :427 (loggercall_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array(1))
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/Model/Table.php  :531    testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user   Model_User->hook("beforeSave")
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/Model/Table.php  :612    testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user   Model_User->save()
/var/www/html/testing/admin/page/mgr.php    :26     testing_admin_mgr_userauth_model_user   Model_User->update()
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :189    testing_admin_mgr   page_mgr->init()
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/ApiFrontend.php  :92     testing_admin   Admin->add("page_mgr", "mgr", "Content")
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php   :332    testing_admin   Admin->layout_Content()
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/ApiFrontend.php  :33     testing_admin   Admin->addLayout("Content")
/var/www/html/testing/atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php   :208    testing_admin   Admin->initLayout()
/var/www/html/testing/admin/index.php   :7  testing_admin   Admin->main()
```

Is it possible to tell BasicAuth to reference the Person model to get the e-mail field, or can we alias the e-mail address some way in the User model?

Cheers

## Update 1

Thanks Jancha,

In order to get the CRUD to display the same fields as before for User and update the password correctly, I made the following changes.

### Person Model

> > same as before.

### User Model

## The 'user' table contains the password field.

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='user';

function init(){
    parent::init();

    $person = $this->join("person", "person_id");
    $person->addField('email')->system(true);

    // hasOne() links the referenced table so CRUD can use 'id' and 'name' for drop down menus, etc.
    $this->hasOne('Person');
}
}
```

### User Auth class

> > Same as before.

### Manager page.

// Administrator manages the tables in the mySQL database.

```
class page_mgr extends Page {

function init() {
    parent::init();

    $tabs=$this->add('Tabs');

    $crud=$tabs->addTab('Users')->add('CRUD');
    $crud->setModel('User');

    if($crud->grid){

        // Add prompt using user model id field.
        $crud->grid->addColumn('prompt','set_password_prompt');

        if($_GET['set_password_prompt']){
            $auth = $this->add('UserAuth');
            // load User from DB using row ID.
            $model = $auth->getModel()->loadData($_GET['set_password_prompt']);

            $model->set('password', $_GET['value'])->save();
            $this->js()->univ()->successMessage('Changed password for '.$model->get('email'))
              ->execute();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The above changes work great, I can successfully update the password of the User.

However....because there is a join() between User and Person. When I select to delete a User entry, the corresponding person in the Person table is also deleted.
From the join() docs: "Queries will join tables, inserts, updates and deletes will be applied on both tables", hence the unintended side effect.

## Update 2

Ok, I think I've solved it by moving the join() to the authentication class. So that the BasicAuth class can access the "email" field. Whilst the CRUD class does not see the join and delete the joined entries in the User model.

### User Model

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code='user';

function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Person');
}
}
```

## User Auth class

```
class UserAuth extends BasicAuth {

function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this->setModel('Model_User', 'email', 'password');
    $this->getModel()->addField('password')->system(true);

    $person = $this->getModel()->join("person", "person_id");
    $person->addField('email')->system(true);

    $this->usePasswordEncryption('sha256/salt');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in your User model, you should rather have following - drop hasOne and instead:

   $person = $this->join("Person.person_id", "id");
   **$person->addField("email");**
2. use `$model->load()` instead of `loadData();`
3. use `$model->save()` instead of `update();`